# IE8 Display problems

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a site that works fine in android browser, FF, Chrome, Safari IE9+ but in IE8 the upper half of an elements background disapears as well as the background color on a couple of input elements.

I have run through IE debugging tools and also W3C and there is nothing that is coming up that would make this occur.

The site in question is http://ukritic.com if anyone can check it in FF then IE8 and maybe suggest what could be causing the problem it would be greatly appreciated.

If you need anything from me let me know and I will post it up for you.

ADDITION:

The problem that is occurring is that in IE8 the white background containing the content is only visible 1/2 way down the page but is hidden on the upper half of the page and also hidden where the facebook like box is located.

In all other browsers the entire content container shows the #FFF background from the top of the page to the bottom of the page.

We have tested in IE compatibility and normal mode but the problem persists.

What I do notice is that while the page is loading the content container is white but as soon as the page loads completely it disappears on the top half and the facebook container.

Thanks
~M

Comment: This question would be clearer if you could point out the specific area of the page that has problems.  I couldn't see anything wrong, at least in IE 8 compatibility mode.

Comment: Typically, it's a poorly written question if the reader should have to load it up in several browsers and make a side-by-side comparison of differences in order to figure out what you're talking about.

Comment: It must be something related with a js script, because when I disable javascript the background shows just fine.

Comment: Thanks that clarifies my concerns I will go through the JS and figure out which script is killing the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the border-radius.htc file as soon as I removed that call the page rendered perfectly.

There really is no effective way of rendering round corners on ie8 as the .htc file needs a relative path to the page that is rendered which does not really work well with dynamic depth address bars (shortUrls).

Guess I will have to settle for rounded corners only in IE9+ and all other browsers.

Thanks for the input